# how to use aggregation of mongodb

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

From the data as given below, I want to sum all Values fields.
Please let me know how can I do it using aggregation functionality of mongodb.

```
{"MetricRecord": 
   { "SchemaVersion" :  "0.12",
     "Product": {
         "ProductName"   : "abc",
         "ProductVersion": "7.5.0.1" ,
         "ProductId"     : "1234567890ABDFGH12345",
         "InstanceId"    : "12345BA32",
         "InstanceName"  : "1234SS123",
         "SystemId"      : "somehost.com" 
         },
     "Tenant" : {
       "CustomerId" : "222-555-124", 
       "ServiceCode": "xyzxyzxyz12345yyy"
         },
     "Metrics" :  [
      {   
       "ReportType" :[ 
          { "report" : "billing" },           
        ],
          "LogTime" : "2013-12-08T12:34:56:01Z" ,
          "Type"    : "AuthorizedUsers",
          "SubType" : "registered",
          "Value"   : "125",
          "UnitOfMeasure": "USD",
        "Period"  :  {
            "StartTime" : "2013-12-07T00:00:00:01Z",
            "EndTime"   : "2013-12-08T00:00:00:01Z"
          }
          },
      {   
       "ReportType" :[ 
          { "report" : "billing" }
        ],
          "LogTime" : "2013-12-08T12:34:56:01Z" ,
          "Type"    : "NumberOfTickets",
          "SubType" : "resolved",
          "Value"   : "430",
          "UnitOfMeasure": "USD",
        "Period"  :  {
            "StartTime" : "2013-12-07T00:00:00:01Z",
            "EndTime"   : "2013-12-08T00:00:00:01Z"
          }
          }
       ]
    }
 }
```

So, results which I expect from summation of values is 430+125 i.e. 555

Comment: The information you posted above appears to already be the results of an aggregation query. If you'd like help pulling certain information, it would be best to post the structure of the original documents in the collection and describe what you'd like to achieve.

Comment: You need to add a [`$group`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) step to your aggregation pipeline and use the `$sum` operator.

Comment: I have replaced above data now with the original data.

Answer (score 0):

Your document contains **string value for MetricRecord.Metrics[index].Value** field and i am not sure why are you trying to sum up the string values. if it is a typo and your document contains **numerical values for MetricRecord.Metrics[index].Value** field then you can try the following query

```
db.metrics.aggregate([
                      {$unwind:"$MetricRecord.Metrics"},
                      {$group:{_id:"$_id",sum:{$sum:"$MetricRecord.Metrics.Value"}}}
                    ])
```

In the above document posted, if your value field is like

```
 MetricRecord.Metrics[0].Value is 125(not "125")
 MetricRecord.Metrics[1].Value is 430(not "430")
```

you will get the following output

```
{
"result" : [
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"),
        "sum" : 555
    }
],
"ok" : 1
}
```

The above sample query is composed assuming you have the default mongodb **"_id"** field and you are using a **metrics collection**. You have to manipulate the query as per you requirements.

Comment: Thanks Amarnath for your help.

Comment: Yes you are right the field value must be integer and not string.Now, I am able to get the expected results. Thanks a lot again.

Comment: @user1961408 may be you can vote up if the answer was helpful and mark right if its right.